# Can't Find Colton

Tags: bakugan-champions-of-vestroia

My son is stuck on this Nintendo Switch game. In order to continue the main story quest we need to 'Talk to Colton' to begin a tournament but we can't find him anywhere.

Normally a yellow indicator appears on the map to show where we need to go to continue a quest, but there isn't one in this case. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

We never got the yellow marker to appear but we did eventually find 'Colton' in Helena Heights Brawl Club and were then able to proceed. After we got past that, the yellow markers started working again.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so, turn off the nintendo switch turn it back on, this accrued to me before I tried multiple things and this worked, the yellow marker should appear

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, I'll try it as soon as I get chance and report back. It's been driving us crazy :)

Comment: Not working so far but I'll keep trying. I'm doing a full shutdown and restart each time